# Rinkeby transaction taking too much time

Tags: transactions, rinkeby

I've sent from one of my accounts to another account some ether's the transaction is verified but the ethers on both accounts are not updated

Transaction Hash: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa2ef91d1200d50c6cb5b024987a27d5c2a35de86e69b15bffde9e5a8db80b218

UPDATE:
I added one more transaction in the opposite direction which doesn't seem to finish as well:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x527a7cbb7e8b7af142dd40d0b89305d2694424ed548a4a1a6ec25846d7e75e23

Comment: This appears to have resolved?
I am interested to know how long it took? Or was it just a matter of resyncing?
Currently there seems to be a sync issue with rinkeby.

Comment: I believe it took less than 24h, so it wasn't really an issue. I have been of the network for a couple of months, so I don't about the current situation.